# Sending Mail with PHP output content won't display on inbox

Tags: php, email, mailer

I have Forgot Password Form where users can enter their valid email address. I have no problem in sending mail to user, my only problem is that i want to send to users their account information from database (Username & Password )so that they will know their username and password. But it seems like I'm having hard time on how to display their account information on the user's inbox. I'm new in PHP and it would be great if you could help me on how to figure it out.

Here's my code:

**Edited:**

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $email_from = "example@domain.com";
    $datesent = date('D m/d/Y, g:i A');
    $error_message = "";
    $msg = "";
    $subject = "Some text here";


    //some validations here

    $query = "Select * from user_information where EMAIL_ADDRESS = '".$_POST['email']."'";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die("ERROR: ".mysql_error());
    $check = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if ($check == 0) {
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        $username = $row['USERNAME'];
        $password = $row['PASSWORD'];
        $fname = $row['FIRST_NAME'];
    }
    ob_start(); //Turn on output buffering
?>

    Hi <? php echo $fname; ?>!

        Here is your Account information:

        Username: <? php echo $username; ?>
        Password: <? php echo $password; ?>

    //some text here

<?php
    $message = ob_get_contents();
    ob_get_clean();
    $email_message = "From: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message. = "Sent: ".clean_string($datesent)."\n";
    $email_message. = "Subject: ".clean_string($subject)."\n";
    $email_message. = "\n".clean_string($message)."\n";
    $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n";
    $headers. = 'To: '.$email."\r\n";
    $headers. = 'Sent: '.$datesent."\r\n";
    $email_sent = @mail($sendto, $subject, $email_message, $headers);
} ?>
```

Comment: Get rid of the `@` in front of the `mail()` function so you actually get to see if there are any errors.

Comment: Seems like there were no errors found when i get rid of the @ symbol of mail().

Comment: if (isset($_SESSION['submit'])) This is the error. session variable submit will be never set so the code inside it will never be executed. when you submit a form, that should $_POST['submit']. basic error

Comment: I'm so sorry but that's just only a typo error, but my real code is actually $_POST['sumbit'].

Answer (score 0):

The following code does not work fpr you:

```
$check = mysql_num_rows($result);
if($check==0){
    ...
 }
```

should be:

```
$check = mysql_num_rows($result);
if($check != false){
    ...
 }
```

You only set the username, password and fname if there is no resulting row

Comment: do you have a debuger like xdebug? If so please debug your code. If not put `error_log('Check: ' . $check);` after `$check = ...` and look into your error_log file

Answer (score 0):

I assume you posted the entire source file. If so, you lack a `session_start()` at the beginning of your file. Without it access to `$_SESSION` is not possible. Or maybe you wanted to use `$_POST` and wrote `$_SESSION` instead?

Comment: i already put session_start() at the beginning of the code but that doesn't make any sense. :(

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if ($check == 0)
```

to

```
if ($check > 0)
```

Note: Don't use $_POST , $_GET variables without sanitizing them. Using mysql_query is prone to sql injection if you do not validate and sanitize your $_POST and $_GET variables. Use PHP_PDO

Also

```
 if (isset($_SESSION['submit'])) {
```

to

```
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
```

Comment: Same as others, this answer doesn't resolved the problem. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

first of all start session then only you can use session variables and when fetching array from database , the number of rows should not be zero , like this

```
 if ($check != 0) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $username = $row['USERNAME'];
    $password = $row['PASSWORD'];
    $fname = $row['FIRST_NAME'];
}
```

and there is mistake in this code also

```
  ob_start(); //Turn on output buffering
  ?>
  Hi <?php echo $fname; ?>!

    Here is your Account information:

    Username: <?php echo $username; ?>
    Password: <?php echo $password; ?>

//some text here
```

you have not used `<?php` but`<? php` instead.
hope that helps.

Comment: thanks for your help but that does not resolved the problem either.

Comment: @tek4granted can you explain how your program is behaving.